# WhatsApp Cloud API Error: Template name does not exist in the translation

Tags: whatsapp, whatsapp-cloud-api

I am currently working on implementing the WhatsApp Cloud API to send a document using a template message. However, I'm encountering the following error:

{"error":{"message":"(#132001) Template name does not exist in the translation","type":"OAuthException","code":132001,"error_data":{"messaging_product":"whatsapp","details":"template name (airline_ticketcopy) does not exist in en_GB"},"fbtrace_id":"Aqd1AxyVmb5OPqBERjlaEdS"}}

The error message suggests that the template name "airline_ticketcopy" does not exist in the translation for the en_GB locale. I've double-checked my code and the template name, but I'm still facing this issue.Template also in Active – Quality pending state.

Here's a snippet of the code I'm using to send the message:

```
{
  "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
  "to": "<TO NUMBER>",
  "type": "template",
  "template": {
    "name": "<TEMPLATE NAME>",
    "namespace": "<TEMPLATE NAME SPACE>",
    "language": {
      "code": "en_GB",
      "policy": "deterministic"
    },
    "components": [
      {
        "type": "header",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "type": "document",
            "document": {
              "link": "<CUSTOM URL>"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "body",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "type": "text",
            "text": "VigneshWaran"
          },
          {
            "type": "text",
            "text": "Erode"
          },
          {
            "type": "text",
            "text": "Chennai"
          },
          {
            "type": "text",
            "text": "Sunday, 10 September 2023 20:30"
          },
          {
            "type": "text",
            "text": "GOLDEN POWER TRAVELS"
          },
          {
            "type": "text",
            "text": "Near Erode Bus Stand"
          },
          {
            "type": "text",
            "text": "Erode Bus Stand"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "button",
        "sub_type": "quick_reply",
        "index": 0,
        "parameters": [
          {
            "type": "text",
            "text": "Manage Your Booking"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Template Body Content :

Dear {{1}}, you have an upcoming journey today from {{2}} to {{3}} at {{4}} with {{5}}.

Boarding Point- {{6}}
Landmark- {{7}}

Live Tracking details for your bus are not available at the moment. We will notify you as soon as they are available.

For more information about your trip

We wish you a comfortable and safe journey.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I have recently fixed this. I tried everything but didn't work. I just leaved it for about 4 to 5 days and after that when I tried it worked.

Sometimes it takes time to propagate the template through the system.

I would recommend you to verify the langauge code of template "en_GB" and wait for 4 to 5 days.